# Why can't I call a function outside a thread? How can I call It?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm trying to call a function that I have outside my thread.

I've a threaded function to pull data from internet and put it on a database.

I need to send that data to registered users after I save it to DB, I've a function that sends it but I can't call it, I don't know why... I've never worked with threads before... Can someone help me out...

This is the function that sends to registered users:

```
def sM(chatId, message):
    yield from bot.sendMessage(chatId, '<code>{}</code>'.format(message), parse_mode='HTML');
```

I need to call it inside the getJSON function, but I don't know how...

Here's the entire code:

```
def sM(chatId, message):
    yield from bot.sendMessage(chatId, '<code>{}</code>'.format(message), parse_mode='HTML');

def getJSON():
    db = Connect('bot.db');
    ultimoCadastrado = '';
    while 1:
        try:
            getJson = requests.get('https://api.import.io/store/connector/0f73e47a-bc1d-490b-924b-8886ac703701/_query?input=webpage/url:https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gatry.com%2F&&_apikey=000c112af5ad4f33b2f40fdfe34ec36ba64eea2cfb0998639867a151bdaf65f498dc0376a779863af592d87e58c3291732681793b89008f48fbc545a9cb4c34eb6ebc3b5a5695508a964ed5cdda7eb9d');
            data = json.loads(getJson.text);

            if('results' in data):
                nomeP = data['results'][0]['nome'];
                valorP = data['results'][0]['valor'];
                linkP = data['results'][0]['link_gatry'];
                findData = re.search('title=\"([^\"]+)', str(data), re.I);
                dataP = findData.group(1);
                if(nomeP != ultimoCadastrado):
                    print('Promoção encontrada! -> ', nomeP);
                    print('Verificando em nossos bancos de dados...');
                    if not(db.checkPromoDuplicate(nomeP, valorP, dataP, linkP)):
                        db.addPromo(nomeP, valorP, dataP, linkP);
''' i need to call it here->            sM('111111', 'Hello i'm calling');'''
                    ultimoCadastrado = nomeP;

            else:
                print('KeyError: a chave não foi encontrada no JSON.');
        except:
            pass

        time.sleep(10);


TOKEN = sys.argv[1];  # get token from command-line

bot = telepot.async.Bot(TOKEN)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
botDB = Connect('bot.db');

threadJson = Thread(target = getJSON);
threadJson.setDaemon(True);
threadJson.start();

loop.create_task(bot.messageLoop(on_chat_message))
print('Listening ...')

loop.run_forever()
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my english or code... I'm learning both...

Comment: You use `yield from` meaning that the function is actually a generator. It's not as simple as calling it, you have to drain the returned iterator. If you don't know what all of that means then please google for "python generators" and read as much as possible. I'm not sure what this `bot.sendMessage` is so it is hard to give you a proper advice.

Comment: I use it as I see on the wiki page of the framework I use. It's called telepot, it's a framework for telegram API. It's working fine to send messages, the problem is that I can't call it inside the getJSON function... it doesn't work

Comment: Again: that's because your `sM` function is a **generator**. You have to drain the result, e.g. `result = sM(...)` and then `for x in result: pass`. It's a weird construct so you have to really really analyze what you are doing here. IMHO it is totally wrong. Maybe it is enough to use `return` instead of `yield from`? I don't really know that framework.

Comment: BTW: don't use semicolons in Python. It's not C.

Comment: I tried with return but It didn't work, nothing. When I use yield from, I can get it working on sending commands to the bot, but I can't get it to call the bot function sendmessage inside the getJSON thread...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you beyond what I've said. Maybe someone else will, good luck.